# Find select lists with ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby, forms, drop-down-menu, mechanize

When looking at a form, I'd like to know if it has any select lists and which fields they are.

e.g.

```
 form.fields_with(type: "selectlist")
```

or

```
form.selectlists
```

Any ideas?
Assume there must be a way of doing it but the docs aren't helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very good answer, but it does at least work to some degree.

```
form.fields.select{ |f| f.respond_to?(:options)}
```